# Odd Behavior in Visual Studio Designer Font

Tags: visual-studio-2005

If I click "..." on the font box of Visual Studio 2005 to set the font of a `Label` and set the font size to Arial 8 point font, Visual Studio sets the size to 8.25pt.  14 gets set to 14.25.  22 gets set to 21.75.  Apparently, the values in this dialog box do not perfectly map to the size value Visual studio is using.

Why does this happen?